# Meu personagem essa dandos uns fliques quando eu ando em direcão a obstaculos - Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Estou fazendo um jogo 3D de câmera fixa na unity e quando ando em direção a uma parede e o personagem colide e eu continuo pressionando pra ir pra frente ele fica indo e voltando como se tivesse tentando atravessar a parede gostaria de saber como que quando o usuario chegar em um obstáculo ele parar e pausar a animação quem poder me ajudar agradeceria <3

o código de movimento do meu personagem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Camera MainCamera;

    //playerMoviment
    public float moveSpeed = 2.8f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float rotationSpeed = 15f;

    private Animator animator;

    private bool inCrunch = false;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update() {
        PlayerCrunch();
        PlayerMoviment();
    }

    public void PlayerMoviment() {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal,0f,moveVertical).normalized;

        movement = MainCamera.transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        movement.y = 0f;


        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
            animator.SetBool("walk",false);
            animator.SetBool("run",true);
            transform.position += movement * (moveSpeed + 1.2f) * Time.deltaTime;
        } else {
            animator.SetBool("run",false);
            if(movement != Vector3.zero) {
                animator.SetBool("walk",true);
            }
            transform.position += movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if(movement != Vector3.zero) {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,targetRotation,rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        } else {
            animator.SetBool("run",false);
            animator.SetBool("walk",false);
        }
    }

    public void PlayerCrunch() {
        if(Input.GetKey((KeyCode.LeftControl))) {
            inCrunch = true;

        } else {
            inCrunch = false;
        }
    }
    


}
```

Comment: Consegui consertar o problema para quem esta tendo o mesmo problema eu apenas deixei de usar o rigidBody e usei o characterController ai ele parou de ficar tentando atravessar as paredes.